# Cannot connect to Mono Server with browser

Tags: asp.net

When I follow these instructions:

ASP.Net Hello World

Create a text file with the name hello.aspx and the content:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Calendar</title>
</head>
<asp:calendar showtitle="true" runat="server">
</asp:calendar>
```

Then run the xsp4 command from that directory:

xsp4 --port 9000

Use a web browser to contact http://localhost:9000/hello.aspx

at this link:http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/

I get this output in the command prompt:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\test>xsp4 --port 9000
xsp4
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\test
Listening on port: 9000 (non-secure)
Hit Return to stop the server.

The browser just idles- seemingly forever with message in the tab-connecting until it finally times out. Anybody have any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The same problem is described [here](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/xsp-not-responding-td4665249.html#a4666422).

I had exactly the same problem as described when trying the hello.aspx example.

I believe this roblem is caused by blank spaces in the paths where Mono is installed
(by deafult in "C:\Programs (x86)").

When I run

> xsp4 --port 9000

on the command line this ultimately is resolved to

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\bin\mono.exe"   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\bin\..\lib\mono\4.5\xsp4.exe" --port 9000

I determined this by looking at the process with [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). When running this the server will have the non-response/hanging problem.

However I had previously set up a symlink "C:\programfilesx86" pointing to "C:\Program FIles (x86)" using [Junction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx). When I use the following command

> "C:\programfilesx86\Mono\bin\mono.exe"  "C:\programfilesx86\Mono\bin\..\lib\mono\4.5\xsp4.exe" --port 9000

I get a response, an asp.net calendar in the case of the hello.aspx example.

So the solution seems to be to either

1. install mono in a directory with no spaces
2. set up symlinks as described above.